# Any difference between "The photographer clicked" and "The photographer clicked away"?

Tags: photography

While *clicked* often seems to be followed by an object, I did find occurences of it being used alone, e.g. in *The photographer **clicked** as Marilyn worked*.

*Clicked away*, however, seems to be used mostly (only?) whithout any object.

But these considerations aside, are there any real differences between the two? I'm not a native speaker, so it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: "Clicked away" implies a bit more randomness -- shots not carefully posed and framed.

Comment: I think "spontaneity" is a better word- just because a photographer shoots a lot of exposures doesn't mean he isn't working hard to make each shot a good one.

Comment: @HotLicks - or that the viewer is just not paying attention to the process enough to note the posing and framing.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz - But it sort of implies that he's not instructing the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Clicked away" is better, as it implies a continual process, which meshes with "as Marilyn worked", while plain "clicked" invokes a single event.

Comment: Yes - *[verb] away* implies *continually* or ***repetitively*** [verbing]. It's often a figurative "spatial" allusion - moving *along* towards some long-term goal, *gradually* getting there. *"It was a huge steak, but he chomped away and eventually finished the lot."*